# run robotframework test cases for tkinter app

Tags: python, tkinter, automated-tests, robotframework

Does someone knows how to create a test case to run and test a tkinter app or know a good python lib or way to test tkinter apps?

I know tkinter has functions to simulate interactions like invoke() for a button widget, so it seems possible that you can make a keyword to press some button in a tkitner app with robotframework. I have only found info about test cases for selenium.